# Importing Jade templates through Webpack in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, pug, webpack

I'm trying to get a grip of present front-end tech, and want to load a Jade template using Webpack. Using Javascript, this works as expected.

`app.js`:

```
import * as foo from "html!jade-html!./header.jade";
document.write(foo.default);
```

But if I rename it to `app.ts`, content unchanged, `webpack` to build:

```
ERROR in ./app.ts
(5,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'html!jade-html!./header.jade'.
```

I'm surprised the module loading semantics would suddenly change using TypeScript. What gives?

Bonus points: can this Jade loading snippet be written shorter?

Comment: For what it's worth, I got the template loading in TypeScript with the `jade-loader` in my loaders array and by using `import * as template from './relative/path/to/template.jade'`. This still gives me a TypeScript error in the console, even though I've even passed in all my .jade files in tsConfig.json via the filesGlob property. Let me know if you get anywhere with this!

Comment: For some reason just using `require('./header.jade')` in an ng2 template declaration worked fine. I don't get it, but okay.

Comment: Strange. I get a TypeScript error when I do `require('./main.jade')`, "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'."

Comment: My `package.json` has `"typescript": "^1.6.2"` in devDependencies, but for some reason it seems the node typings are not built in?

Comment: @JaKXz: Good question... I know for sure I faced this same issue as well. I actually can't find the answer anymore (been trying other things over the last month), but if you wish to try and compare, I've uploaded what I have right now over [here](https://github.com/tycho01/front). Hope it might help you -- sorry I don't have any better answer right now.

Comment: Yeah it is strange. Installing the typings for node solved it for me. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Hah, great. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript assigns special meaning to the `import` keyword (it's expecting an actual module). You should instead define a `require` function and use `var foo = require('...')` (note `var` instead of `import`).

Here's an example of a require definition [from the ts-loader docs](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#loading-other-resources-and-code-splitting).

```
declare var require: {
    <T>(path: string): T;
    (paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
    ensure: (paths: string[], callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => void) => void;
};
```